# Google maps - get infoWindow content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PlaceID finder</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .controls {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 29px;
        margin-left: 17px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        outline: none;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      .controls:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="map"></div>
<input style="margin-left:5px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Store Point" id="addNewStore" />

    <script>
      // This sample uses the Place Autocomplete widget to allow the user to search
      // for and select a place. The sample then displays an info window containing
      // the place ID and other information about the place that the user has
      // selected.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
          }

          // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
          marker.setPlace({
            placeId: place.place_id,
            location: place.geometry.location
          });
          marker.setVisible(true);

          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
              'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
              place.formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }

$("#addNewStore").on("click", function () {
            //i need these variables
            //...=place.name;
            //...=place.place_id;
            //...=place.formatted_address;

           /$.ajax({
                url: '/Store/Add',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    PlaceName:place.name,PlaceID:place.place_id, Address:place.formatted_address
                },
                success: function (results) {
                    alert("Successfully added new store");
                }, error: function (data) {
                    alert("failed to add store");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The sample is from google maps documentation and I find it very useful for me.
My problem is that I can't use the infoWindow content in my anonymous function, which the button calls.
I tried with 2 ways of constructor functions, but I didn't figure it out.
Thank you in advance ^^

Comment: What is your question?  Did you try making the infowindow variable global?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get all the infoWindow content as different variables if it's possible.

Comment: If you want to use `place` object outside the `initMap`, make it global. eg. before the `function initMap()` set `var place;` And remember removing the `var` from `var place = autocomplete.getPlace();`

Comment: It was the first thing that i tried, and a lot more things like JavaScript constructor functions, but it doesn't work. Maybe the problem is not in working with JavaScript, but with google maps objects that i declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teacher showed me an easy way how to do it.

In the body you should add div without anything visual in it.
After setting the marker to be visible get the class `.hidden-data` and u can add as much attributes as you want for every property of the marker.

```
   <div class="hidden-data" data-place="" data-location="" data-address=""></div>
                marker.setVisible(true);

                $(".hidden-data").attr('data-place', place.name);
                $(".hidden-data").attr('data-location', place.geometry.location);
                $(".hidden-data").attr('data-address', place.formatted_address);
```

The jQuery function which will be called on button click should looks like:

```
$("#addNewStore").click(function () {
    var a = $(".hidden-data").attr('data-place');
    var a = $(".hidden-data").attr('data-location');
    var a = $(".hidden-data").attr('data-address');
});
```